# Internet Explorer doesn't work while using Outlook

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, microsoft-outlook-2003

When I restart my laptop Internet Explorer work fine, 
But when I use MS outlook, error TCP/IP error -  Cannot find server gets shown.

In Internet Explorer it immediately goes to page cannot display error (without trying to load at all)

And some time if I restart my laptop and try to open Outlook, it tries download about 2GB email from server. After a while, I notice that it has stopped downloading.

If I restart and open IE directly its work fine, the problem is with MS outlook

I use Windows XP with Outlook 2003 & Kaspersky Antivirus 6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many things that could be causing the problems that you are seeing.  It could be low disk space, a damaged drive, Outlook causing heavy disk access making the system sluggish (2GB is quite a substantial amount of data for it to deal with), or it could even be a malware infection.

The first thing to do would be to clean out any old and unwanted data using some software such as [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) or [IOBit Advanced SystemCare](http://www.iobit.com/advancedsystemcareper.html), both of which may be able to free up enough space for Outlook to work properly and SystemCare may also potentially fix other related problems.

Next I would run a full disk scan in order to identify potential defects with the disk. From [How to run Chkdsk from My Computer or from Windows Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315265) I would scan for defects on the disk, as detailed below.  Note that this may take quite a while on large drives.

> 1. Double-click My Computer, and then right-click the hard disk that you want to check.
> 2. Click Properties, and then click Tools.
> 3. Under Error-checking, click Check Now. A dialog box that shows the Check disk options is displayed,
> 4. Use one of the following procedures:
>
>    - To run Chkdsk in read-only mode, click Start.
>    - To repair errors without scanning the volume for bad sectors, select the Automatically fix file system errors check box, and then click Start.
>    - **To repair errors, locate bad sectors, and recover readable information, select the Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors check box, and then click Start.**
>        Note If one or more of the files on the hard disk are open, you will receive the following message:
>
>      - The disk check could not be performed because the disk check utility needs exclusive access to some Windows files on the disk. These files can be accessed by restarting Windows. Do you want to schedule the disk check to occur the next time you restart the computer?
> 5. Click Yes to schedule the disk check, and then restart your computer to start the disk check.

You also state you are using Kaspersky 6, that product was [End-of-life'd back in 2008](http://support.kaspersky.com/kis6mp2?level=2) and you may want to look into updating to something a bit more modern as your first option, as it is probably not providing any real protection against current threats.  I've detailed a few options below.

```
Support status:     
 End of Life
 Supported until: 2008 Sep 01
 Database updates supported until: 2009 Sep 01
 Latest version number:     6.0.2.621
```

Given the age of you machine and prevalence of malware of all forms on the internet I would look at updating to any of the free alternatives such as [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx), [AVG Free](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/homepage), [Avast](http://www.avast.com/en-gb/index) or any other of the free alternatives.

I would also recommend running [Malwarebytes Antimalware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (the free version) to see if there is anything else that might be causing a problem.

Comment: @Khalid Did any particular step fix the problem for you?

Comment: Thanks you Moukubai, the problem was with my antivirus. when i pause it it work fine !. thank you again

Comment: Fair enough, glad you got around the problem.  :)